# Does canon mention Helga Hufflepuff's chamber?

Tags: harry-potter

I've searched high and low and I was certain that this was in the second canon book, but I can't find it. I distinctly remember Professor Flitwick joking that anyone seeking out the Chamber of Secrets should instead seek out "*Helga Hufflepuff's Chamber of Hard Work and Practice*" (or some words to that effect). Have I made this up or stole it from some fan fiction? Or is it really in a Rowling book?

Comment: A quick Google search for "Helga Hufflepuff's Chamber of Hard Work and Practice" doesn't return any matches.

Comment: @F1Krazy That's largely why I appended "(or some words to that effect)".

Comment: https://twitter.com/lambdatotoro/status/995655583738023936?t=hItSH3uT4x4PTXMrxAy38g&s=19

Comment: https://nicdevera.wordpress.com/2021/04/18/notes-on-harry-potter-and-the-methods-of-rationality-by-eliezer-yudkowsky/

Comment: Not in anything Rowling has ever written. I don't *think* it's from any licensed material either though that's harder to verify. Probably a fanfic.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Yeah looks like it's HPMOR - https://www.hpmor.info/73.html#12599

Comment: @F1Krazy - How did you not find HPMOR? Bing doesn't show it, sure. hmm.

Comment: And now this is one of the top results on a google search for "Helga Hufflepuff's Chamber of Hard Work and Practice". Given that the answer shows this exact phrase is present in the book, i wonder why the book text itself does not show up on google, given how popular that fanfiction is

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per ibid's comment, this is a joke from the fanfic [*Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Methods_of_Rationality):

> "Excuse me," Hannah said in a tone that was polite, but firm. "How did we win? And why does the ceiling look all melty?"
>
> There was a pause.
>
> "Susan did it," said Tracey.
>
> "Yeah," said Parvati, voice only slightly shaky as she stood up and started to brush off her red-trimmed robes, "it turns out that Susan Bones is the Heir of Hufflepuff and she's opened up the long-lost entrance to **Helga Hufflepuff's Chamber of Hard Work and Practice**."
>
> "Huh? " said Hannah, who was feeling over herself as if to make sure all her body parts were still there. "**I thought that was just something Professor Sprout says to teach us an Important Moral Lesson** - Susan is?"
>
> <sub>Source: [Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality, chapter 73](https://www.hpmor.info/73.html#12599); emphasis added</sub>

It's mentioned as something Professor Sprout says, rather than Professor Flitwick. The chapter was originally posted in 2011.